# How can I set a notification (badge) on default_icon in chrome extension next to the browser toolbar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

How can I set a badge on default_icon in chrome extension next to the browser toolbar? When I click `play` I want to set  to the `play` badge(icon). When I click `stop` I want to set a stop badge. When I click the third button, the icon disappears. How to set it? Is it possible?

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <style>
        button {
          height: 30px;
          width: 30px;
          outline: none;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <button id="setBadgeIconPlay">Play</button>
      <button id="setBadgeIconStop">Play</button>
      <button id="deleteBadgeIcon">Badge</button>
      <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

**manifest.json**

```
  {
    "name": "Getting Started Example",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Build an Extension!",
    "permissions": ["notifications"],
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
    },
    "page_action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_icon": {
        "16": "images/get_started16.png"
      }
    },
    "icons": {
      "16": "images/get_started16.png"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2
  }
```

**background.js**

```
  chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"icon.png"});
```

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. Simply use setIcon like you do now and specify different icon paths depending on the state which you can save inside chrome.storage.local or in localStorage. P.S. a badge is an established API term that means the small text label beside the icon, you can change it via [setBadgeText](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-setBadgeText).

Comment: I want to click button in popup.js and call ` chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:"AAA"})`. Click button ---> set badge beside the icon. How connect button to call setBadgeText?

Comment: Put that code in popup.js and replace page_action with browser_action in manifest.json. No need for background.js for this task.